# Calling API key from Info.plist in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

i am pretty new in IOS development and currently learning about basic stuff related to IOS development. I recently see an article about storing your API key in info.plist so that it can store more securely, I followed the instruction but looks like I made a mistake, so what did I do wrong? if there's any good resources please do comment bellow, thanks

How I call my API key in view in swiftUI

```
var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            ScrollView{
                VStack(spacing:0){
                    //MARK: Top Content of HomeView
                    // This view represent a content located on the very top of homeview
                    HomeViewTopContent()
                    Text("API KEY : \(Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["API_KEY"]  as? String ?? "API KEY GA KE FETCH")")
                    //MARK: Main content
                    List{
                        switch self.ViewState {
                        case .load:
                            ListItemShimmer()
                        case .done:
                            ForEach(0..<5){_ in
                                ListItemShimmer()
                            }
                            .animation(.linear)
                        case .failed:
                            Text("Data not loaded, please do refresh")
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.width, height: UIScreen.height)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(width: UIScreen.width, height: UIScreen.height)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
```

How I store my API key
[image: API Key in Infoplist]

Result
[image: Result]

Comment: You say storing the API key "more securely". More securely than what?  Reading the contents of the info.plist file is pretty trivial. There isn't any truely secure way of storing an api key in an app, but the info.plist is probably the least secure.

Comment: Can you share where you read about storing API key in Info.plist.

Personally, I store my API key in keychain, that is the most secure way.
Once you type it in, signin or whatever, store it and read it back from keychain.
It's a bit more involved but very secure.

Comment: it's more like an easier way : https://medium.com/swift-india/secure-secrets-in-ios-app-9f66085800b4

Comment: for the keychain, are there any resource I could learn from? aside from the documentation

Comment: I use this library: "https://github.com/evgenyneu/keychain-swift".
The trick I found to make it work, was to make sure in "signing & Capabilities" in Xcode,  
the "Keychain Sharing" is added and the "keychain groups" has some string 
like "com.xxx.appp". Then it's like using UserDefaults.

Comment: well thank you, i probably gonna use it for my personal projects, but this one is for educational purposes, thus I cannot use it 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, you're looking for `"API_KEY"`, but in your `Info.plist`, you've defined it as `"API Key"` -- note the capitalization difference, underscore, etc. -- it's important that there is an exact match.

Change the key in your `Info.plist` to `API_KEY` and your code will work as expected.